# How to rollback Query on Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, rollback

I am suck on a major issue. By mistake I executed a bunch of sql files on my QA database. Because of that, application is facing severe issue.

So I want to rollback all those scripts. I am using Oracle SQL developer and Oracle 11g.

Is it possible in this tool to rollback a bunch of scripts upto some some Checkpoint/Save Point ?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your only options are restore from backup or write and run your own undo queries.

Comment: Ok,first, what Version of Oracle? Were the unwanted updates to a specific table?  Or a set of tables?  If it was just a single table, it mat easily be addressed from flashing back table .  (Depending on Oracle version, of course.)

Comment: Hi, I am using Oracle 11g. And the DML were performed on a set of tables. There are about 7 tables which got affected after DML Execution.